# Surface area of intersection of two spheres

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral

[image]
I got these two sphere (both are hollow, sorry i cant illustrate it by my drawings). The small sphere with radius $r$ and big sphere with radius $2r$. I just want to find the area of the shaded region. (i hope it clear that the region is made by the small sphere cut out the large sphere)

I got the answer which is $2 \pi r^{2}$ which i think is half the curved surface area of the hemisphere but i don’t know why, to me it should be the area of a circle with radius $r$ but i may be wrong. Please give me the hints but not full solution

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Area or volume?

Comment: The area depends on the distance between centers of spheres. I guess you mean the center of the small sphere lying on the big sphere, but you have not specified that and I may guess wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle connecting the centers of two spheres and one intersection point is an isosceles triangle with side lengths $(r, 2r, 2r)$. The angle $\theta_0$ between the legs is given by

$$\sin\frac{\theta_0}2 = \frac{\frac{r}2}{2r} = \frac14 \implies \theta_0 = 2\arcsin \frac14$$

The surface you're after is a [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Volume_and_surface_area) with central half-angle $\theta_0$.

Its surface area is

$$A = \int_{\phi = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{\theta = 0}^{\theta_0} r^2\sin\theta \,d\theta \,d\phi = 2\pi r^2 \int_{0}^{\theta_0} \sin\theta\,d\theta = 2\pi r^2 (1-\cos\theta_0) = \frac14\pi r^2$$

since $$\cos\theta_0 = \sqrt{1- \sin^2\theta_0} = \sqrt{1-4\sin^2\frac{\theta_0}2\cos^2\frac{\theta_0}2} = \sqrt{1-4\sin^2\frac{\theta_0}2\left(1-\sin^2\frac{\theta_0}2\right)} = \frac78$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why it is $\frac{r}{2}$ when you calculate the $\sin\frac{\theta_0}2$ ?

Comment: @Thy $\theta_0$ is the angle at the vertex between the legs (sides of length $2r$), and the base has length $r$. The height from the vertex to the base bisects the triangle into two right triangles, each having the angle $\frac\theta2$ at the vertex. Now apply basic trigonometry of the right triangle.

Comment: May i also ask why it is $r^2$ in the integration? Thank you ;)

Comment: @Thy The surface element in spherical coordinates is given by $dS = r^2\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates).